# Preselect value in list and add to text box on tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a comment box where a user can type @ to show a list of users that they can add to the comment. Those users will then be notified. A sample comment could be:

@steve and @bill did you see @travis?

Here is the existing code:

HTML:

```
input.comment-text ng-model="comment.text" ng-change="showUserList(comment.text) ng-trim="false"

ul.user-list [ng-show="usersShow"]
  li.user [ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="addUserToComment(user.username)"]
    span
      strong
        | {{user.username}}
      | {{' : ' + fullName(user)}}
```

JS:

```
$scope.showUserList = function(comment) {
  var pattern = /(?:^|\s)@\S*$/;
  $scope.usersShow = pattern.test(comment);
};

$scope.addUserToComment = function(user) {
  $scope.comment.text += user + " ";
  $scope.usersShow = false;
  $('.comment-text').focus();
};
```

When the user list pops up I want to have the first user preselected. If tab is pressed it will then put the username into the text box. Also, they can arrow up and down and hit tab on any users to put that user in the comment box. How do you capture a tab event to trigger this process? Would the best way be by using the keycode on keypress? How do you turn a ul into a list where you can navigate with the arrow keys? Thank you for your help.

Comment: uhm, are you re-building stackoverflow.com?

Comment: lol Yes. That is exactly what I'm doing.